# Where to put implicit wait in Page Object Model?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a POM setup with

```
SearchPage
LogInPage
```

and then a Test file.

The SearchPage and LogInPage have all the locators, action methods (find, click, send keys) etc.

Currently in my Test file I have:

```
  [TestInitialize]

    public void Setup()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        
    }
```

One of the tests looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void LogIn()
{
    var searchPage = new SearchPage(driver);
    var url = searchPage.GetUrl();
    try
    {
        url.Should().Be(SearchPage.searchURL);
        log.Debug("The LogIn test passed!");
    }
    catch(AssertFailedException ex)
    {
        log.Debug("The LogIn test failed", ex);
    }
  

}
```

My question is, will that ImplicitWait in the [TestInitialize] carry across all Page Objects and methods/actions that are being called through the Tests themselves?  Or is it only applicable to whatever actions happen on that Tests page itself (i.e. do I need to put the implicit wait in every Page class)?

BTW I realize explicit waits are probably better to use, but I want to get the hang of this first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit waits apply to all page models using that specific instance of the web driver.

See [Implicit Wait Commands in Selenium WebDriver C#](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/implicit-wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver-c/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Greg.  So it looks like where I have it placed is correct for handling all page classes (and whatever lies within) that are referenced in my Tests.

Comment: Link was helpful.

Answer (score -3):

When we doing page object model mostly we occour nullpointexception because every page should need create object.

if you create utils class for wait you can use it anywhere in project

```
 **public WebElement waitForElement(By locator, int timeout)
{
    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until
            (ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
    return element;
}**
```

Comment: The question was about `ImplicitWait`, not `WebDriverWait`. This does not answer the question.

Comment: implicit wait explicit wait are now not using in selenium frameworks ,webdriver waits are usifull